# Chrome Extension - Manifest V3 URL Capture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm having issues using regexFilter to capture URL and redirect it to the extension page. On Chrome I end up with broken URL and endless redirection loop. On brave I get ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT. I'm trying to capture any MPEG-DASH or HLS streaming URL to play it inside the extension.
Service worker looks like this:

```
var enabled = true;

var extension_page = chrome.runtime.getURL('/index.html');
var substitution = extension_page + "#\\0"

var rules = [{
  id: 1,
  action: {
    type: 'redirect',
    redirect: { regexSubstitution: substitution },
  },
  condition: {
    regexFilter: '^https?://.*/(.*\\.m3u8?|.*\\.mpd|Manifest).*',
    resourceTypes: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
  },
}];

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request == "getState") {
        sendResponse(enabled);
        return;
    }
      
    enabled = request == "ENABLE";
    enabled ? chrome.action.setIcon({path: "assets/icon128.png" }) : chrome.action.setIcon({ path:"assets/icon128grey.png" });

    if(true === enabled) {
        chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
            removeRuleIds: rules.map(r => r.id),
            addRules: rules,
        });
    } else {
        chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
            removeRuleIds: rules.map(r => r.id)
        }));
    }
});

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: rules.map(r => r.id),
    addRules: rules,
});
```

manifest.json looks like this

```
{
    "name": "Native MPEG-Dash + HLS Playback",
    "version": "5.0.0",
    "description": "Allow the browser to play HLS (m3u8) or MPEG-Dash (mpd) video urls 'natively'",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": { "128": "assets/icon128.png" },
    "background": { 
        "service_worker": "new_service_worker.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "declarativeNetRequest",
        "storage"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Native MPEG-Dash + HLS Playback",
        "default_icon": "assets/icon128.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Using an example I end up with extremely wrong redirect loop:

```
https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fpschrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#chrome-extension://iepdffliopgmnnmohpmdhclhdhkoonea/index.html#.mpd
```

On Brave I end up with ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT. Furthermore, pasting streaming URL directly into Brave address bar works.

This solution was found at [Get original URL when redirecting via declarativeNetRequest + extensionPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73391252/get-original-url-when-redirecting-via-declarativenetrequest-extensionpath/73392754#73392754)

I tried different variations of regex which didn't work.

Comment: This code cannot produce such a redirect, so there must be a mistake inside index.html's script or an old wrong rule is still active, which you can see by checking the output of getDynamicRules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that there were some old rules flapping in the breeze somehow, even though I removed and reinstalled the extension completely. So instead of doing this by itself

```
var rules = [{
  id: 2,
  action: {
    type: 'redirect',
    redirect: { regexSubstitution: substitution },
  },
  condition: {
    regexFilter: '^https?://.*/.*\\.m3u8?|.*\\.mpd|Manifest.*',
    resourceTypes: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
  },
}];

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: rules.map(r => r.id),
    addRules: rules,
});
```

I used getDynamicRules to remove all previous rules and added the correct one after that

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules().then(function(oldRules) {
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
        removeRuleIds: oldRules.map(r => r.id),
        addRules: rules,
    });

    console.log(chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules());
});
```

I still have ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT on redirect.

EDIT

Resolved the ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT by adding web_accessible_resources as suggested here [Chrome Blocking Redirect to Extension Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68038854/chrome-blocking-redirect-to-extension-page/77864592)

```
"web_accessible_resources": [{ 
    "resources": [ "/index.html" ],
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
}]
```